# How can you find the unit group of this ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am interested in the rank of the unit group $R^\times$ for the ring $$R = \mathbb{Z}[X,Y,Z]/(X^2+Y^2+Z^2-aXYZ-b)$$ for integers $a,b$ with $a\neq 0$, $b\neq 0$ and $a^2b\neq 4$. I expect this rank to be $0$, but so far I am not sure how to prove this.

One idea I had was to instead look at $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,Z]/(X^2+Y^2+Z^2-aXYZ-b)$ and hope that the units in this ring are only rationals. Then we can use an isomorphism to $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,Z]/(Z^2-(X^2Y^2-X^2-Y^2+a^2b/4))$ and after some rewriting it seems that we need to find two polynomials $P_0,P_1\in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ that satisfy $P_0^2-(X^2Y^2-X^2-Y^2+a^2b/4)P_1^2\in \mathbb{Q}^\times$. Moreover if this corresponds with a unit $P_0+zP_1$ outside of $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ we must have $XY | P_1$ and $P_0$ minus some constant is divisible by $X^2Y^2$. But I have not been able to show that such $P_0,P_1$ do not exist.

Another thing that this reminded me of is Dirichlet's unit theorem, and if we for instance use evaluation homomorphisms we can say something about the unit group of certain quotients of $R$.